# How to find the unique product among the stores using spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am new to Apache spark. I want to find the unique product among the stores using scala spark.

Data in file is like below where 1st column in each row represents store name.

```
Sears,shoe,ring,pan,shirt,pen
Walmart,ring,pan,hat,meat,watch
Target,shoe,pan,shirt,hat,watch
```

**I want the output to be**

```
Only Walmart has Meat.
only Sears has Pen.
```

I tried the below in scala spark, able to get the unique products but don't know how to get the store name of those products. Please help.

```
val filerdd = sc.textFile("file:///home/hduser/stores_products")

val uniquerdd =  filerdd.map(x=>x.split(",")).map(x=>Array(x(1),x(2),x(3),x(4),x(5))).flatMap(x=>x).map(x=>(x,1)).reduceByKey((a,b)=>a+b).filter(x=>x._2==1)

uniquerdd holds - Array((pen,1),(meat,1))
```

Now I want to find in which row of filerdd these products presents and should display the output as below

```
Only Walmart has Meat. 
Only Sears has Pen.
```

can you please help me to get the desired output?

Answer (score 0):

The dataframe API is probably easier than the RDD API to do this. You can explode the list of products and filter those with count = 1.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

df = spark.read.csv("filepath")

result = df.select(
    $"_c0".as("store"),
    explode(array(df.columns.tail.map(col):_*)).as("product")
).withColumn(
    "count",
    count("*").over(Window.partitionBy("product"))
).filter(
    "count = 1"
).select(
    format_string("Only %s has %s.", $"store", $"product").as("output")
)

result.show(false)
+----------------------+
|output                |
+----------------------+
|Only Walmart has meat.|
|Only Sears has pen.   |
+----------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. I am a beginner in spark.. just started with RDD. Could you please expand my solution and help me to get the result. So that I can learn step by step. Thanks in advance.